# Programmatically add an attachment sets a wrong permalink

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a few hundreds of PDFs and I try to upload them programmatically in Wordpress and attach them in a custom post type with Advanced Custom Fields.

This is part of my code where I create the attachment

```
function update_attachment( $f, $pid, $file_url ){
        
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $pid, $f );
    
    if( empty( $file_url ) ) 
        return false;

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $file_url ), null );

    // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $file_url ), 
        
        'post_parent'    => $pid,
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $file_url ) ),
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    );

      $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_url );

    return array(
        'pid' => $pid,
        'url' => $file_url,
        'attach_id' => $attach_id
    );

}

//create the custom post type
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'post_title' => $file['Title'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',  
    'ping_status' => 'closed',   
));

//Create the attachment in Media
$att = update_attachment( 'file', $post_id , 'migration/' . $file['FileName'] );

//Save the attachment to the ACF field
update_field('field_5eeb34e23731c', $att['attach_id'], $post_id );
```

The `$file` variable is an array where I have created before this code and contains the info of the pdf.

The post is created with the correct attachment. However, the permalink of the media file is the one from the post I created.

`mydomain.org/resources/filename/‎`

So, when I open the url `mydomain.org/wp-content/uploads/migration/filename.pdf` it redirects to the url above.